# Should I repeat AsNoTracking when performing multiple joins?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When  I perform muliple joins is it enough that I call `AsNoTracking()` as below once or I need to repeat it multiple times for each `context.Ys` and `context.Zs` or rather just call `AsNoTracking` before `ToList()`. Will this cause different behaviour?

```
from x in context.Xs.AsNoTracking() where x.Id == id
join y in context.Ys on x.Id equals y.XId
join z in context.Zs on x.Id equals z.XId
```

Comment: You should define it ONCE. It's just maker to do not track entities. IMHO, better to do that before materialisation.

Comment: Just once.  Also where tables are related to one another, leverage navigation properties within the entities rather than explicit `Join` statements. `Join` is provided to handle loose relationship scenarios where FKs are not available. EF is designed to map tables and relationships, not merely a Linq replacement for SQL.

Comment: @StevePy I agree, but it's not my call. I would use navigational properties everywhere. I don't like those joins but I'm forced to use them.